# Loading a json file using python resulting in an error

Tags: json

Goof mourning,

When I am trying to load a json file into a mongodb, I am getting the following error:

```
raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded").
```

In my opinion, my problem come from my second field, but I do not know how to make change "" into a name, or delete it before to load it.

My json file is :

```
{ 
"_id" : "585a9ecec62747d1e19497a5", 
"" : NumberInt(0), 
"VendorID" : NumberInt(2), 
"lpep_pickup_datetime" : "2015-11-01 00:57:34", 
"Lpep_dropoff_datetime" : "2015-11-01 23:57:45", 
"Store_and_fwd_flag" : "N", 
"RateCodeID" : NumberInt(5), 
"Pickup_longitude" : -73.9550857544, 
"Pickup_latitude" : 40.6637229919, 
"Dropoff_longitude" : -73.958984375, 
"Dropoff_latitude" : 40.6634483337, 
"Passenger_count" : NumberInt(1), 
"Trip_distance" : 0.09, 
"Fare_amount" : 15.0, 
"Extra" : 0.0, 
"MTA_tax" : 0.0, 
"Tip_amount" : 0.0, 
"Tolls_amount" : 0.0, 
"Ehail_fee" : "", 
"improvement_surcharge" : 0.0, 
"Total_amount" : 15.0, 
"Payment_type" : NumberInt(2), 
"Trip_type" : NumberInt(2), 
"x" : -8232642.48775, 
"y" : 4962866.701, 
"valid_longitude" : NumberInt(1), 
"valid_latitude" : NumberInt(1), 
"valid_coordinates" : NumberInt(2)
}
```

Comment: As you use Python, please tag your question with it.

Comment: Please show the code that is trying to read this data in by clicking the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43866216/edit) link and updating your question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your JSON file is not the empty-string key (that is allowed), but the occurrences of `NumberInt(...)`: this is not valid in JSON. You need to provide the number without wrapping it in some kind of function.

So this will be valid:

```
{
    "_id": "585a9ecec62747d1e19497a5",
    "": 0,
    "VendorID": 2,
    "lpep_pickup_datetime": "2015-11-01 00:57:34",
    "Lpep_dropoff_datetime": "2015-11-01 23:57:45",
    "Store_and_fwd_flag": "N",
    "RateCodeID": 5,
    "Pickup_longitude": -73.9550857544,
    "Pickup_latitude": 40.6637229919,
    "Dropoff_longitude": -73.958984375,
    "Dropoff_latitude": 40.6634483337,
    "Passenger_count": 1,
    "Trip_distance": 0.09,
    "Fare_amount": 15.0,
    "Extra": 0.0,
    "MTA_tax": 0.0,
    "Tip_amount": 0.0,
    "Tolls_amount": 0.0,
    "Ehail_fee": "",
    "improvement_surcharge": 0.0,
    "Total_amount": 15.0,
    "Payment_type": 2,
    "Trip_type": 2,
    "x": -8232642.48775,
    "y": 4962866.701,
    "valid_longitude": 1,
    "valid_latitude": 1,
    "valid_coordinates": 2
}
```

If you have no control over the non-JSON file, then after reading the file contents replace the occurrences of `NumberInt` like this (in Python):

```py
import re
json = re.sub(r"NumberInt\((\d+)\)", r"\1", json)
```

Comment: import re                                                                                                      json = re.sub(r"NumberInt\((\d+)\)", r"\1", data_link)

print json                                                                                                                 am I correct?

Comment: Should I replace json by: with open('/home/sebastien/SF2/test/test.json', 'r'). I am still getting an error: TypeError: expected string or buffer.

Comment: That is just a matter of reading a file in variable. For instance: `with open('myfile', 'r') as f: json = f.read()`, and then continue with the code I provided.